# How to disable the header at any page in ConTeXt?

Tags: header-footer, context

I haven't written an article since I paid my attention to ConTeXt. Now it is a chance to do it. I have tried to set the header, but failed.

The structure of this article is like this:

```
... title ...(Line-Breaking Algorithm)
\section{...}
...
\section{...}
...
\section{...}
...
```

My question is that how can I disable the header at page 1 but enable it other than page 1, and the header text is always `Line-Breaking Algorithm` ?

Comment: Do you use any structure element like title, chapter, section, or makeup on the first page?

Comment: @Aditya the title was designed by using some boxes and the first section was at the same page with the title. No chapters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the command
[setupheader](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupheader) to
temporarily suspend the header. Here's an example:

```
\setupheadertexts [Line-Breaking Algorithm]
\starttext

Header present \page

\setupheader [state=stop]
No header \page

\setupheader [state=start]
And the header is back

\stoptext
```

If you use chapters or sections, those commands might change the settings you
made manually. You can control the header behaviour of the sectioning commands
with the `\setuphead[header=…]` setting.

If you want to disable the header on a title page, the
command [startmakeup](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup) may
be useful. It disables the header by default and has a `headerstate` setting
for further fine tuning.

*Edit:* Here's another solution using a conditional:

```
\setupheadertexts [\doifnot\pagenumber1{Line-Breaking Algorithm}]
\starttext
  No header \page
  Header present
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks，Marco. But when I write the words, I won't know where the ConTeXt begins a new page because I don't use `\page` to force a new page. Also, the title, the author are at the same page with the first section.

Comment: In plain TeX, I can use the `\if-like` commands to compare the page number with number 1, so if the page number equals 1, it won't display the header. In ConTeXt, it seems as if I can't modify the output routine.

Comment: Aha! That's it! thanks, Marco. By the way, where can I learn this `\if-like` tricky in ConTeXt？

Comment: @TimLi To get started have a look at [the ConTeXt wiki - System Macros](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/System_Macros/Branches_and_Decisions) or if you feel more adventurous have a look at `syst-aux.mkiv`. Or start reading some of the modules included in the distrubution for some use cases of what you actually can do with these low level macros.

Comment: yeah, I will follow your advice. Reading the ConTeXt codes is really a big challenge for me, but it is very interesting.